# ignore hosts file in ZSH ssh/scp tab-complete

Tags: zsh, hosts

I use a hosts file to block ads/malware domains. When I use ssh or scp in zsh and try to tab-complete, it takes a good 5-10 seconds before anything appears and what does appear is usually a list of 20+ domains I have blocked, and buried in there is the file I need.

I've search online quite a bit, and found helpful hints of how to add this sort of auto-completion, but I can't figure out how to remove it. I basically never want the tab-complete to search my hosts file (I use known-hosts for the servers I actually do want to tab-complete to).

This is on OS X.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try adding the following to your zshrc

```
zstyle ':completion:*' hosts off
```

Comment: Or `zstyle -e ':completion:*' hosts 'reply=($myhosts)'` to complete hosts from an array of your choosing (that example is [from `zshcompsys(1)`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Overview-2).

Comment: you can also use zstyle -e ':completion:*' hosts /my/special/hostfile

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have thousands of hosts in my hosts file and it save me a lot of tabs ;)

Comment: Doesn't work. It causes ZSH to complete `off` as a host. This works though: `zstyle -e ':completion:*' hosts 'reply=()'`

Comment: None of the above worked for me. Adding `hosts` after the star did the trick though:
`zstyle ':completion:*:hosts' hosts off`